# Re-occured systems lockup

Tags: windows-xp

I am using an Hp compaq6000 pc, recently i discovered while working on the system i often encounter lockup(freeze), especialy when an external device like a flash drive is slot in.What could be the possible caused of this problem?

Comment: HP 6000 series of laptops are prone to motherboard problems/failures, can you look on the sticker and post your HP product number?...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/findModel?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a new machine, I would take a guess on it possibly crashing due to age of machine, and only noticing/coincidence that it happens with USB devices.

Alternatively, Lockups without Bluescreens/similar are usually down to hardware failure - this could be memory/hard drive loosing connection or similar. If you can, check that all cables/connections are in properly and consider reseating the memory.

For the last, it could be inserting a USB stick is jogging the board which causes these problems.

I fear it won't but I hope this helps.

If it is a new machine, all I can suggest is try to update drivers - in particular motherboard/chipset as it is possible you have a dodgy USB controller.